# How to apply the "Run as Administrator" option for all executables in a folder

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, runas

I have a Windows 7 PC in which I have a folder with a lot of `.exe` files in it.

I want to grant Administrator privileges by default to all these executables: I can do it by picking them one by one, then go to `Properties` -> `Compatibility` and tick the `Run as Administrator` option.

But I have 30+ executables, so doing it for each of them would take a lot of time.

Is there any way to do it? Maybe there is a terminal command that can do that?

I tried selecting all the executable and then going to `Properties`, but the `Compatibility` tab disappeared.

Comment: It looks like a crooked nail. Why do you want to do this at all? Maybe there is better solution?

Comment: I agree with @LogicDaemon. Can you explain what you want to do, and have you tested if all the programs require this permission? If you're trying to do some security by using this method so a limited user would not have access, bare in mind that just not allowing that user to access these files is a much better option. If you think that by doing this the user suddenly gets access, you're mistaken. It'll prompt a UAC dialog and the user needs to give credentials.

Comment: @LPChip I have a bunch of exe files in a folder, they all need administrator permissions. techie007's solution seems to be right

Comment: @Harlandraka aha. If its right, why haven't you accepted the ansewr yet?

Comment: @LPChip Because I am on mobile and I can't try it right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can programmatically set the "Run this program as an administrator" flag (the option you find in the Compatibility tab of an EXE's properties), by setting a simple registry key. You need to create a string value (REG_SZ) under one of these keys (if you want the setting to be per user or per machine, respectively):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

or

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers

The name of the value needs to be the full path to your executable (if the path contains spaces, do not surround the path with quotes) and the data of the value must contain the string `RUNASADMIN`.

[Source of above info (from SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2739459/225906)

Here's an example PowerShell script that will apply the flag (for the current user) to all EXE's in the current folder:

```
$exes = Get-Item *.exe
New-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags" -Name "Layers" -Force
foreach ($exe in $exes) {
     New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" -Name "$exe" -Value RUNASADMIN -PropertyType String -Force
}
```